# Join two tables containing csv files to query

Tags: sql, sqlite, csv, foreign-keys

I have two csv files, one regarding Artists and one regarding Billboard 100 songs that look like this:

**Artist** (First 4 rows)

[image]

**Billboard** (First row)

[image]

Now I have to write a SQL query to print each artist along with the number of albums they have released and the number of Billboard100 songs they have, which requires me to join the two tables. My schema for the two tables looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Artist(Artist_ID int not null primary key, 
                    Artist varchar(30), Followers int, 
                    Genres varchar(200), NumAlbums int, 
                    YearFirstAlbum int, Gender char(1), 
                    Group_Solo varchar(5) ); 

CREATE TABLE Billboard(Song_ID int not null primary key, 
                    Artists varchar(90), Name varchar(20), 
                    Weekly_rank int, Peak_position int, 
                    Weeks_on_chart int, Week Date, Date varchar(20),     
                    Genre varchar(20), Writing_Credits varchar(20), 
                    Lyrics varchar(10), Features varchar(20) );
```

and this is the outcome for the first few rows when I inserted the csv files:

[image]

Now do you know what is the best way to query to print each artist along with the number of albums they have released and the number of Billboard100 songs they have the file given that I did not insert a foreign key into the billboard table? Or I should revise my schema?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can a song have multiple artists? if so how are you storing those? the way you write the query depends on that as well. What is considered Billboard100 song? I would recommend storing artist_id instead of artist name in the billboard table.

Comment: Yes it can, I am storing those as having multiple artists considered as an artist, so for instance if ed sheeran did a song alone and a song with camila cabelo there would be two artists and two songs (Ed Sheerand and Ed Sheeran, Camila Cabelo). Billboard 100 songs are all contained in the billboard table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend removing Artist from Billboard and creating a new table to hold the artists and their song (especially given that a artist can be in solo and group). It is not recommended to have multiple values in same column in SQL. Also, it is best to store the id rather than the artist name itself.

You could create a table like below :

```
CREATE TABLE Artist_Billboard
(Artist_id int,
Song_id int,
FOREIGN KEY(Artist_id) REFERENCES Artist(Artist_id),
FOREIGN KEY(Song_id) REFERENCES Billboard(Song_id))
```

Once you create this table it will be really easy to pull the information that you need. All you have do is :

```
select a.Artist, NumAlbums, count(ab.artist_id) Billboard100
from Artist_Billboard  ab
join Artist a on a.Artist_id = ab.Artist_id
group by a.Artist, NumAlbums
```

DB Fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a3e9ec59b590e2cbeea0668e2eac0bc1

**Update on the question on comment below :**
I am not sure I understand your question. If you are asking about how you would identify the song_id and artist_id and perform a insert please see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=973235257b17dff0900f8adfe6afcd6d

Currently the song name and artist name is hardcoded. You would have to do something similar.

Comment: Thank you so much for your extensive answer. Can I ask you the last thing? When you do "insert into Artist_Billboard" is there a way to insert the ids coming from the artists and billboards tables by making match the artists id with their songs id?